# token=android.os.BinderProxy error android?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-places-api, gmsplacepicker

I am using google place picker for in android but when it opens it immediately stop before you can pick a place.

this is the code

```
  try {

    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is the error

> token=android.os.BinderProxy@3431c3eb  Timeline: Activity_idle id:
>   android.os.BinderProxy@3431c3eb time:37045782

Comment: Is `Avt_AddRestoran2` an Activity? If so, try removing `.this` and see if this works.

Comment: yes it is an activity.I Removed but t is not workng?Thanks for helping

Comment: Are you doing this inside an Activity or a Fragment. If you are doing it inside an activity, then you can pass `this`. Actually, please paste the rest of your code here so we can examine it more closely as well.

Comment: inside an activity

Comment: OK, in that case then try something like this: `startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);`

Comment: It is still giving the same thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111792/discussion-between-kader-kabore-and-ishmaelmakitla).

Comment: What ended up being the solution? I am having something similar happen now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39032081/no-permissions-pop-up-anymore

Comment: what is the solution?