# No Permissions Pop Up Anymore?

Tags: java, android, google-oauth, android-permissions

So I am creating an app that requests permission to a users google account. I used mine to test and so I gave it permission and then removed it to see if it would ask for it again. It was still using the token it got so I deleted the app from my phone and reinstalled it. I didn't change any code and now all of a sudden it only shows the account page (to select which account) and then once I press ok, nothing shows to give it permission. In my run console I get the following:

```
$ adb push C:\Users\James Singleton\AndroidStudioProjects\ChffrAPI\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 25029 on device samsung-sm_g935v-0d75cc0d
E/Zygote: v2
W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0010
E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10269
I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
W/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi 
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
D/RelationGraph: garbageCollect()
I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
D/ContextRelationManager: ContextRelationManager() : FEATURE_ENABLED=true
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi rsrc of package com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi
D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi-2/lib/arm64
W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/dpmapi.jar': I/O Error
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi-2/lib/arm64
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi
I/InjectionManager: Constructor com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi, Feature store :{}
I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
D/RelationGraph: garbageCollect()
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi rsrc of package com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi rsrc of package com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi rsrc of package com.google.android.gms
I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Reading stored module config
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000007/n/arm64-v8a
D/ChimeraFileApk: Primary ABI of requesting process is arm64-v8a
D/ChimeraFileApk: Classloading successful. Optimized code found.
D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.WifivsDataDialog isFragment :true
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{3c6164c V.E...... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.MainActivity isFragment :false
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{ead695 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : c0299d7, I241dab1ec4
          Build Date                       : 01/25/16
          OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
          Local Branch                     : 
          Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.HB.1.1.1.06.00.01.063.117
          Remote Branch                    : NONE
          Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7f62194188
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
I/InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.MainActivity
I/InjectionManager: dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.MainActivity
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@7d80ce5 time:2598350
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/WifiManager: isAllowWifiWarning() -> isCscWifiEnableWarning : false ChinaNalSecurityType : 
D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 1128) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 1128) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:android time:2603031
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{65ce05f token=android.os.BinderProxy@7d80ce5 {com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.MainActivity}} show : true
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@7d80ce5 time:2605454
V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{65ce05f token=android.os.BinderProxy@7d80ce5 {com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi/com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.MainActivity}} show : false
Application terminated.
```

Nothing changed in my code so I have no idea why I am not getting the pop up to allow me to give the app permission.

Here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context mContext = MainActivity.this;
    private AccountManager mAccountManager;
    private AuthPreferences authPreferences;
    EditText emailText;
    TextView responseView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    static final String API_KEY = "";
    static final String API_URL = "https://api.comma.ai/v1/auth/?access_token=";
    static final String ClientId = "45471411055-m902j8c6jo4v6mndd2jiuqkanjsvcv6j.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    static final String ClientSecret = "";
    static final String SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
    private static final int AUTHORIZATION_CODE = 1993;
    private static final int ACCOUNT_CODE = 1601;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        responseView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseView);
        emailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailText);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        final Context context = this;
        mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
        authPreferences = new AuthPreferences(this);


        SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (authPreferences.getUser() != null && authPreferences.getToken() != null) {
                    doCoolAuthenticatedStuff();
                    new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();
                } else {
                    chooseAccount();
                }
            }
        });
//        Button queryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.queryButton);
//
//        queryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                if (isNetworkAvailable() == true) {
//                    new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();
//                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NavDrawerActivity.class);
//                    startActivity(intent);
//                } else {
//                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Network Service, please check your WiFi or Mobile Data Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                }
//            }
//        });

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean dontShowDialog = sharedPref.getBoolean("DONT_SHOW_DIALOG", false);
        if (!dontShowDialog) {
            WifivsDataDialog myDiag = new WifivsDataDialog();
            myDiag.show(getFragmentManager(), "WiFi");
            myDiag.setCancelable(false);
        }

    }

    private void doCoolAuthenticatedStuff() {
        Log.e("AuthApp", authPreferences.getToken());
    }

    private void chooseAccount() {
        Intent intent = AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[]{"com.google"}, false, null, null, null, null);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACCOUNT_CODE);
    }

    public void requestToken() {
        Account userAccount = null;
        String user = authPreferences.getUser();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        for (Account account : mAccountManager.getAccountsByType(GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE)) {
            if (account.name.equals(user)) {
                userAccount = account;
                break;
            }
        }

        mAccountManager.getAuthToken(userAccount, "oauth2:" + SCOPE, null, this, new OnTokenAcquired(), null);
    }

    private void invalidateToken() {
        AccountManager mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
        mAccountManager.invalidateAuthToken("com.google", authPreferences.getToken());
        authPreferences.setToken(null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == AUTHORIZATION_CODE) {
                requestToken();
            } else if (requestCode == ACCOUNT_CODE) {
                String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                authPreferences.setUser(accountName);

                // invalidate old tokens which might be cached. we want a fresh
                // one, which is guaranteed to work
                invalidateToken();

                requestToken();
            }
        }
    }


    public class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
        @Override
        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
            try {
                Bundle bundle = result.getResult();
                Intent launch = (Intent) bundle.get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
                if (launch != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(launch, AUTHORIZATION_CODE);
                } else {
                    String token = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);


                    authPreferences.setToken(token);
                    System.out.println(authPreferences);
                    doCoolAuthenticatedStuff();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            Log.e("Network Testing", "Available");
            return true;
        }
        Log.e("Network Testing", "Not Available");
        return false;
    }


    class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private Exception exception;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            responseView.setText("");
        }

        protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {

            // Do some validation here

            try {
                URL url = new URL(API_URL + authPreferences.getToken());
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
                int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println("GET Response code:" + responseCode);
//                urlConnection.addRequestProperty("client_id", ClientId);
//                urlConnection.addRequestProperty("client_secret", ClientSecret);
//                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "JWT " + authPreferences);
                Log.i("URL", url.toString());
                try {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    return stringBuilder.toString();
                } finally {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            if (response == null) {
                response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.i("INFO", response);
            responseView.setText(response);
            //
            // TODO: check this.exception
            // TODO: do something with the feed

//            try {
//                JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
//                String requestID = object.getString("requestId");
//                int likelihood = object.getInt("likelihood");
//                JSONArray photos = object.getJSONArray("photos");
//                .
//                .
//                .
//                .
//            } catch (JSONException e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }
        }
    }}
```

And then here is my AuthPreferences.java

```
public class AuthPreferences {
    private static final String KEY_USER = "user";
    private static final String KEY_TOKEN = "token";

    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    public AuthPreferences(Context context) {
        preferences = context
                .getSharedPreferences("auth", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_USER, user);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void setToken(String password) {
        Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_TOKEN, password);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return preferences.getString(KEY_USER, null);
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return preferences.getString(KEY_TOKEN, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you revoke the permission? until you revoke it, it will never ask for permission again

Comment: Yea I stated that in the original I think. Furthermore, if I have given it permission the Choose Account dialog shouldn't even pop up. So everything is revoked, it just isn't showing me the next pop up or dialog whatever you want to call it. I am thinking it is to do with:

V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{7ba60fe token=android.os.BinderProxy@7d80ce5

Comment: you can also call prompt consent and it should force them to reauthorize your application.

Comment: @DaImTo right but that prompt isn't even showing anymore :/ that is the issue.

Comment: You can prompt the user to re-authorize your app by adding the prompt=consent parameter to the authentication request. When prompt=consent is included, the consent screen is displayed every time the user logs into your app. For this reason, include prompt=consent only when necessary.

Comment: So what would that look like? Because before I got the BinderProxy error everything worked fine. I picked an account, gave permission and it was good to go. I even removed the permission before. And now I'm getting the binder proxy error. The only thing I've added/modified before revoking is the HttpURLConnection. But that shouldn't keep the accept or deny permission box from coming up.

Comment: Anyone else have any idea on what could possibly be causing this BinderProxy?

Comment: Please make sure you SHA and pakage are right in the developer console .This is the more likely the problem.

Comment: I think so because if I bypass this and then go into google maps and come back t the login screen it works -_-